# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.lammatizer'

Tags: python-3.x

```
    from spacy.lammatizer import Lemmatizer
    from spacy.lang.en import LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES
    lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(LEMMA_INDEX, LEMMA_EXC, LEMMA_RULES)
    lemmatizer('chuckles','NOUN')
```

while trying to run the above code, I get the following error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.lammatizer'

Comment: it looks like it should be `spacy.lemmatizer` not `lammatizer`.

Comment: mportError: cannot import name 'LEMMA_INDEX' from 'spacy.lang.en' (/home/srikanth/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/lang/en/__init__.py)

when I used right spelling I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled:

```
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
```